# Windows Mobile - Capture Application/Process Termination Event

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, watchdog

I need to create Watchgog application that will keep track of main application. If my main application is crashed/closed/ended by any means, this watchdog application will activate it again.

I can do this by scanning running process at regular intervals, but this is resource intensive process. Can I get any notification when process is terminated (not Form Closing event, it does not work when application crashes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process class does give you such functions.

> WaitForExit() (method)    Instructs the Process
>   component to wait indefinitely for the
>   associated process to exit.
>   Exited (event)    Occurs when a process exits.

So you need to find your process only once and than in your watchdog use provided method or event.

Comment: An simple alternative to trying to find the process back is to let the watch dog actually start the process.